# Django limiting query

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with django pagination. In my table I have 13,618 records but do pagination, I do not return results.

```
>>> from api.models import Post
>>> posts = Post.objects.all()
>>> posts.count()
13618
>>> posts = Post.objects.all()[10:10]
>>> posts.count()
0
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your slicing:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()[10:10]
```

You're asking for the 10th item to the 9th (10-1) item, which is an empty list. The same would happen if you did this:

```
ls = [1,2,3]
ls[1:1]  # => []
```

It looks like you want 10 items starting from the 10th, in which case you should do:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()[10:20]
```